# Is there way to create bundle identifier without the corresponding app with Fastlane?

Tags: fastlane, fastlane-produce

I'm using `produce` to create my app on App Store Connect. It works well but it seems that the command does not allow creating bundle identifier without an associated app.

I just want to create extra bundle ids that I will use later for ad hoc distribution on Microsoft AppCenter.

Is there a way to do that with `produce` or any fastlane plugins?

The only way I found is using the App Store Connect web interface or this REST endpoint:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/register_a_new_bundle_id

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to create those bundle ids using Spaceship

(https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/spaceship/docs/AppStoreConnect.md#bundle-id-auth-key)

Comment: It would be cool if you added som code here.